# cups problem with embedded buildroot

Tags: embedded, cups, buildroot

I have a embedded linux created with buildroot project. i install cups, cups-filter and `ghostscript` and configure `cupsd.conf` file! also i add my hp 1102 printer using cups web interface on port 631. now when i start a test print i got nothing. my `/var/log/cups/error_log` is as follows:

```
E [15/Dec/2016:16:03:29 +0000] Filter \"imagetopdf\" not found.
E [15/Dec/2016:16:03:29 +0000] Filter \"imagetoraster\" not found.
```

can any body help me?
thanks